# react native layoutanimation config easeInout not working (IOS)

Tags: react-native, layout-animation

i have a room list, when any room have new message, I sorted this room to top then re-render the flatList with LayoutAnimation(testing from IOS simulator):

```
const CONFIG = {
  duration: 300,
  create: {
    type: LayoutAnimation.Types.linear,
    property: LayoutAnimation.Properties.opacity
  },
  update: {
    type: LayoutAnimation.Types.easeInEaseOut
  },
  delete: {
    type: LayoutAnimation.Types.easeInEaseOut,
    property: LayoutAnimation.Properties.opacity
  }
}

export function animate () {
  LayoutAnimation.configureNext(CONFIG)
}
```

but when data changed, i didnt see any animation without fade, as video below:

[video](https://streamable.com/7juyga)

Updated video with transition:

[this is updated answer with transition](https://streamable.com/pm8stn)

other information:

```
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "^0.68.0",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.5.0",
"react-native-reanimated": "^2.9.1",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Archive that you can use `Animated` in `React Native`, you can check this article that explains how to do it step by step from [here](https://itnext.io/animated-list-reordering-in-react-native-secrets-revealed-3192cc33fe4f)

And you can achieve that with `FlatList` by using `Transitioning View` from `react-native-reanimated` like this example:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  StyleSheet,
  FlatList,
} from 'react-native';
import { datas, sortRoom, currentUser } from './components/datas';
import { RoomItem } from './RoomItem';
import { Transition, Transitioning } from 'react-native-reanimated';

    const transition = (
      <Transition.Together>
        <Transition.Change durationMs={500} />
      </Transition.Together>
    );

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      item: {
        width: '100%',
        height: 100,
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        marginVertical: 10,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
      },
      itemText: {
        fontSize: 21,
        color: '#fff',
      },
    });

export default function App() {
  const [roomList, setRoomList] = useState(datas);
  const parentRef = useRef();

  return (
<React.Fragment>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          //get random room and append to top by assign SendDate to now
          parentRef.current.animateNextTransition()
          const newRooms = [...roomList];
          const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * roomList.length);
          const matchedNewRoom = [...roomList][randomIndex];
          matchedNewRoom.LastMsg.SendDate = new Date().getTime();
          const sortedRoom = sortRoom(newRooms);
          setRoomList(sortedRoom);
        }}
        style={{
          marginTop: 20,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
          padding: 5,
        }}>
        <Text style={{ color: 'blue' }}> Re-Order </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
     <Transitioning.View ref={parentRef} transition={transition}>
      <FlatList
        style={{
          width: '100%',
        }}
        data={roomList}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.RoomName.toString()}
        renderItem={({item}) =>  <RoomItem room={item} currentUser={currentUser}/>}
        contentContainerStyle={{
          flexGrow: 1,
        }}
        initialNumToRender={20}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
      />
    </Transitioning.View>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

You can check the demo [here](https://snack.expo.dev/OaTMieaDU?platform=android).

Comment: hi bro, so the problem is *** keyExtractor***? I dont know what difference between ***item.RoomName.toString()*** and ***`${item.RoomId}${index}`***, can u help me explain it?

Comment: Yeah, you need to make the KeyExtractor value the same as the value that you depend on the reorder list.